# Html/Php como alterar o conteudo da pagina de acordo com o final inserido

Tags: php, html, css

Tenho um HTML aqui que uso para gerar Players em Meu Site

Porém tenho que ficar mudando o conteudo do arquivo para acessar Videos Diferentes

Gostaria de Sabe se há uma forma de Mudar a Area:

```
De acordo com a url inserida Exemplo

www.site.com.br/Player.html?video=video.mp4;img=img.png

Teria que mudar o Arquivo para Php?
Por Favor me Ajude não tenho experiencia com Programação WEB
```

HTML:

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640px" height="267px"
      controls preload="none" poster='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/fVcZErSWa7gyENuj8IWp8eAfCnL.jpg'
      data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
    <source src="" type='video/mp4' />

  </video>
```

Comment: Por que gostaria de usar PHP ? seu site é em PHP? acho que um javascript já resolve.

Comment: Utilizo Wordpress, Porém não faço a minima ideia de como fazer isso!

Comment: Se seu player é apenas isso, você poderia sim fazer um programa simples em PHP que use os argumentos do ``$_GET`` para preencher o que vai aparecer no vídeo. Só que você vai ter que aprender um pouco de PHP, se quiser começar pelo manual: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode apenas usar as variáveis $_GET do endereço. Seguindo seu exemplo (consertei o separador de `;` para `&`:

```
www.site.com.br/Player.php?video=video.mp4&img=img.png
```

Você tem dois atributos, "video" e "img", e os valores deles. Então o PHP fica bem simples:

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640px" height="267px"
  controls preload="none" poster='<?= $_GET['img'] ?>'
  data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
<source src="<?= $_GET['video'] ?>" type='video/mp4' />
```

O resultado seria:

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640px" height="267px"
  controls preload="none" poster='img.png'
  data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
<source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
```

Dá pra depois você melhorar o código pra não mostrar o vídeo se, por exemplo, não tiver nenhum argumento, mas aí seria melhor você sentar e aprender a programar mesmo.